# Google Script: function that insert new row copying functions/formulas from last row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table which cells have functions/formulas, like this one:

[image]

I need a script that create a new row copying to it the functions/formulas of the last used row.
I find [this script which create a new row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143705/google-spreadsheet-insert-rows-and-copy-down-hidden-content) but it doesn't copy functions/formulas. How could I implement this formatting copy task in Google Script without having to manually select and copy?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy formulas just as easily you copy values, just use `Range.getFormula()` and `Range.setFormula()` instead of `.getValue()` and `.setValue()`. See [documentation on spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormula%28%29).

Inserting a row below the last one is pretty basic, use [insertRowAfter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowAfter%28Integer%29) and [getLastRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow%28%29) in a simple script.

---

EDIT : in case you don't find it, here is an example of another simple way to do it, [copying  everything in one step](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#copyTo%28Range,Object%29)

```
function duplicateLastRow(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.insertRowAfter(ss.getLastRow());
  ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),1,1,ss.getLastColumn()).copyTo(ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method [Sheet.appendRow](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) allow append row in one command as atomic action.